# Print to a specific printer from Adobe Reader from a vb script running on the server

Tags: printing, vbscript, adobe

I run a vb script on our server, that is called from a client.

My script should print a pdf label to a specific printer.

I works with ordinary print on a laser printer if I copy the file to the printer like this:

```
'Create the filesystem object

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get a reference to the folder you want to search

set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

'loop through the folder and get the file names

For Each Fil In FLD.Files

If UCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(Fil.Name)) = "PDF" Then

FSO.CopyFile Fil.path, "\\servername\printername"

End If

Next
```

but this does not work with labels. When I try the label printer goes in error mode. :-(

It works if I do this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

objShell.run chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" & chr(34) &
" /p /h " & chr(34) & "filepath\filename" & chr(34)
```

but then it prints to the default printer.

That is also okay but for some reason I can't set the default printer from the script called by the client. Only if I log on to the server and run the script manually.

This is what I do to set the default printer:

```
Set objNet = CreateObject("Wscript.Network")

objnet.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\servername\printername"

objnet.SetDefaultPrinter "\\servername\printername"
```

Therefore I tried this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )

objShell.run chr(34) & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" & chr(34) &
" /t " & chr(34) & "filepath\filename" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & "\\servername\printername" & chr(34) &
" " & chr(34) & "drivername" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & "portname" & chr(34)
```

but when I run this Adobe opens and shows the file and nothing else happens. :-(

Does anyone know how I can either get the SetDefultPrinter to work or the ....\ArcroRd32.exe /t "filename" "printername" "drivername" "portname"?